# Problems with message passing queue linux

Tags: linux, ipc, message-queue

I'm writing simple message passing exercise and have sent a message from one process to the next. It's the battleship game.

However other process keeps waiting on the message.

Code is http://pastebin.com/Lc5xxXdu

Sample input:

[image]

First 4x4 board is initalized for both players (e.g.):

```
oooo
----
oooo
----
```

Then target coordinates are entere (e.g. 0 0). This process sends message to other one (using message_t, long pid is in place of mtype in kernel code).

But it's not working for some unknown reason.
Quick translations:

```
Cekam poruku %pid --> Waiting for message
Saljem poruku %pid --> Sending message with following pid (mtype for kernel) set
Ispali na polje --> Nice query where to shoot next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. I accidentally had pointer to pointer instead of only one level of pointers. It got to issue I was having.